# How to ask your line manager about career growth? How is he seeing me for the next higher position?

Tags: career-development

I have completed 2 years in my current job and in these 2 years I have achieved more compared to my other colleagues. All the other department people as well as my state team are aware of the work and voluntarily initiatives that I have taken in the past, however my immediate manager says that he has very little visibility of my work along with this he stated that I am not open.

Promotions cycle is on the corner and this type of comments/feedback is making me worried on the opinion that the manager has drawn towards me and my work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my immediate manager says that he has very little visibility of my
>   work

This appears to be the primary problem.

Talk with your manager. Discuss ways you can give him more visibility into your work.

In the past, I've used Weekly Status Reports to keep my boss in the loop. For me, that was particularly helpful when my boss worked in a remote office. I included headers for each of the major projects and tasks assigned to me, with bullet points detailing the activity for the week. I tried to keep it to 2 pages or less. It seemed to help.

For you, such a Status Report might work. Or, you might instead propose a 1-on-1 weekly meeting to discuss your work status. Or the two of you might come up with something different.

Find a way to work together to a solution.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response.. can you share with me a sample of your any weekly Status Report...

Answer (score -1):

> "my immediate manager says that I do not get a raise because of: blah blah blah blah, blah blah-blah blah"

One strong/overwhelming possibility is this:

When someone does not want to spend more money on you, and you ask why: they open their mouth and **various words** tumble out.

These words have absolutely no actual meaning, because, quite simply: the person simply does not want to hand out raises.

{Thus, say you *absolutely fixed* problem P and came back for another discussion. The manager in question would then just say, "Oh, I can't give you a raise because blah blah blah blah, blah blah-blah blah" and other different words would tumble out. The words have absolutely no meaning - they are just the air vibrating due to the muscles in the manager's throat.}

If this is the case - and it is almost certainly the case - you have precisely one option.

Get a new job for more money.

---

Note - the *particular* reason this manager spouted to you ("no visibility") is comic and meaningless.  Of course manager knows what you are doing, and could spend 30 seconds looking at your output.  It's just a nonsense phrase.
 The manager is all-but *explicitly and overtly saying to you* "If you want more money try another company."